# How to apply CSS to QHeaderView section based on some condition

Tags: python, css, qt, pyside

In the qTableWidget header, I've setup a QMenu, which pops up on right click and offers unique elements from the column, to filter the data.
I want to give it a different style if any column is filtered

Before when no CSS was applied to my application, I was applying style like this, and it was working fine...

```
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(55, 182, 144))
self.table_widget.horizontalHeaderItem(3).setBackground(brush)
```

But after applying CSS to the whole application, above code has no effect.
I tried to set property on the header section, so that I can later style it through CSS based on dynamic property like this

```
self.table_widget.horizontalHeaderItem(3).setProperty('filtered', True)
```

But, since QTableWidgetItem is not derived from QObject, I can't set dynamic property to it!? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Perhaps you can apply a modified version of the app's CSS to the `self.table_widget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)`?

Comment: Yup, but for that I need to assign a property to the header section, in order to style that property through CSS. But as I've mentioned in the question, I can't do this as QTableWidgetItem is not dervied from QObject.